# Water level in a cylindrical container so as to cover a cube upon immersion

Tags: algebra-precalculus

I have created this problem today.  Suppose you have a cylindrical container with base area $A$, you fill it with water up to a level of $h$.  Then you have a cube of side length $a$, that can be assumed to sink to the base of the container.  What must $h$ be such that after placing the cube in the water (and it is squarely on the base of the container), the water covers the cube by a height of $d$ (that is, the water level becomes $a + d$).

So, to solve this problem, I first found the volume of water before immersion of the cube, which is simple $V_1 = A h $, Then the second volume is $V_2 = a^3 + V_1 = A (a + d) $

Thus  $ A (a + d) = A h + a^3 $

From this, $h$ must be set at $ h = a + d - \dfrac{a^3}{A} $

Is my reasoning correct?

Comment: Yes your reasoning and work seems correct to me